# Importar arquivo CSV para SQL - Delphi

Tags: sql-server, delphi, csv

Tenho um programa em Delphi que importa determinado arquivo CSV para um banco SQL afim de depois comparar os dados entre versões diferentes do mesmo arquivo, por exemplo uma versão do arquivo é do dia 01/09 e outra do dia 15/09, a finalidade do programa é comparar o que mudou

Primeiro o programa importa os dados do CSV para um objeto JvMemoryData e depois executa em laço uma ADOProc que faz o insert no SQL com os dados desse JvMD por linha

Ocorre que o CSV tem um padrão de 38 colunas e algo prox de 1 milhão de linhas! Como o cliente não usa toda a informação na planilha fiz uma opção de importação rápida que faz o input somente das colunas utilizadas, mas mesmo assim o processo de leitura e importação do arquivo demora até 50 min

Como posso deixar isso mais rápido?

Comment: Adiantando o assunto, no artigo **Importação de dados em massa** você encontra dicas de como fazer a importação usando comandos SQL -> https://portosql.wordpress.com/artigos/